# unexpected return of rtrim function in PHP

Tags: php, return

when i use:

```
rtrim('HeaderController', 'Controller');
```

i'm expecting to this will return Header because HeaderController - Controller = Header
but this returns 'Head', why?

Comment: the second argument is a list of characters, not a full word.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to remove the "Controller" substring you can do it like this:

```
$name = 'HeaderController';
$shortName = str_replace('Controller', '', $name);
```

to be sure to replace only "Controller" in the end of the string you need a regular expression (which is a little slower)

```
$name = 'HeaderController';
$shortName = preg_replace('/Controller$/', '', $name);
```

The $-sign marks the end of the string

Answer (score 2):

`rtrim` expects a character list to remove, not a substring. So `rtrim` removes the `er` in `Header`.